# Why is the following code not allowing me to get user input with fgets yet works with scanf?

Tags: c, scanf, user-input, fgets

This is a short excerpt from a bigger program, but the rest of the program is irrelevant since I think I was able to isolate the issue. I suspect that it has something to do with the way I'm using fgets. I've read that it's preferable to use fgets over scanf, but I can't seem to get it to work properly here. When I use the following code, the program doesn't give me a chance to enter the number (but simply skips to the while loop which checks if the number entered is in the correct range):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    // ask user for how many items to store
    printf("how many words would you like to enter? (1-%i): ", SIZE);

    // save number of words user would like to store
    char *input = malloc(sizeof(char));
    fgets(input, 1, stdin);
    // scanf("%c", input);

    int words = atoi(input);

    printf("the number of words is: %i\n", words);
    while (words < 1 || words > SIZE)
    {
        printf("please enter a number between 1 and %i: ", SIZE);
        scanf("%i", &words);
    }
}
```

Here's the output I get:

```
~/workspace/extra_stuff/hash_tables/ $ ./test2
how many words would you like to enter? (1-10): the number of words is: 0
please enter a number between 1 and 10:
```

As you can see, it never let me enter the number, but simply moved on to the next step seemingly assuming I didn't enter anything.

If I change the code as follows, everything works as planned:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    // ask user for how many items to store
    printf("how many words would you like to enter? (1-%i): ", SIZE);

    // save number of words user would like to store
    char *input = malloc(sizeof(char));
    // fgets(input, 1, stdin);
    scanf("%c", input);

    int words = atoi(input);

    printf("the number of words is: %i\n", words);
    while (words < 1 || words > SIZE)
    {
        printf("please enter a number between 1 and %i: ", SIZE);
        scanf("%i", &words);
    }
}
```

P.S.: I do realize that if using scanf, I could immediately store the input to an int variable w/o using atoi to convert char to int; however it seems that fgets requires a char *, so that's why I chose this route. Also, I realize that I'm supposed to `free(input)` later.

Can someone explain this behavior? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to everyone who has replied so far! Some helpful suggestions there, but it looks like I'm having the same issue further in my program. Here's the code excerpt:

```
// ask for strings
    for (int j = 0; j < words; j++)
    {
        char buffer[4096];
        // fgets(buffer, 40, stdin);

        // name=calloc(NAME_SIZE, sizeof(char));
        // fgets(name, NAME_SIZE, stdin);

        // printf("size of (array[j]->next)->text is: %lu\n", sizeof((array[j]->next)->text));

        printf("please enter string #%i: ", j);

        fgets(buffer, 4096, stdin);

        printf("you've entered: %s", buffer);

        int length = strlen(buffer);
        printf("word length: %i\n", length); 
}
```

When I run the program, it once again doesn't give me a chance to enter my input when it's supposed to:

```
please enter string #0: you've entered: 
word length: 1
```

---

**EDIT #2:**

After working through David's answer and referencing other people's comments and other SO threads, I've come up with the following version of the code, which first asks the user for the number of words they'd like to enter (and validates the input) and then asks the user to enter those words (again, validating the input). It seems to be compiling w/o errors and warnings and functioning properly, though I am not 100% sure I've tested all the possible things that could go wrong with the user input, and there are some bits of the code I still don't completely understand (I'll list them below) -- if anyone has time/desire/patience to look through it and tell me if I can still improve something, please let me know. My goal is to use this code in another program that will ask for user input and store the entries in a hash table.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE_WORDS 4096
#define BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS 256
#define MAX_WORDS 10

int word_input(int num_words);

void empty_stdin();

int main(void)
{
    int num_words = 0,       /* number of words to enter */
        word_count_check = 0;          /* word count */

    char buffer[BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS] = "";    /* buffer of sufficient size for input */

    for (;;) /* loop continually until valid input of NUMBER OF WORDS USER WANTS TO ENTER or user cancels */
    {
        printf ("how many words would you like to enter? [1-%d]: ", MAX_WORDS);
        // check for cancellation of input
        if (!fgets (buffer, BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS, stdin))
        {
            fputs ("user canceled input\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        // check if user simply hit enter w/o typing anything
        if(buffer[0] == '\n')
        {
            printf("please enter a value\n");
            continue;
        }


        size_t inlength = strlen(buffer);

        // validate length < BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS - 1
        if (inlength >= BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS - 1)
        {
            fputs ("input exceeds allocated buffer size\n", stderr);
            return 2;
        }

        if (inlength && buffer[inlength - 1] == '\n')
        {
            // printf("hurray!\n");
            buffer[--inlength] = 0;
        }
        else if (inlength == BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS - 1) /* the line was too long */
        {
            printf("you've entered too many characters... please stick to a maximum of %i\n", BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS);
            empty_stdin();
            continue;
        }

        // make sure user actually entered a proper int
        if (sscanf (buffer, "%d", &num_words) != 1) /* sscanf is used for conversion */
        {
            fputs ("invalid conversion to int; please provide valid input\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }

        // check if the number entered is out of range
        if (num_words < 1 || num_words > MAX_WORDS)
            fprintf (stderr, "%2d out of valid range.\n", num_words);
        else
            break; /*if the input has been validated, we can now break out of the for loop */
    }

    // call the word_input function and store its return value in word_count_check
    word_count_check = word_input(num_words);

    // check if the number of words processed equals to the number requested by the user
    if(word_count_check == num_words)
    {
        printf("success!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("something went wrong, since word_count_check != num_words...\n");
    }

}

int word_input(int num_words)
{
    int word_count = 0;

    for(;;) /* loop until word_count == num_words is achieved */
    {
        // declare an array for storing input string
        char buffer[BUF_SIZE_WORDS];
        char valid_input[BUF_SIZE_WORDS];

        // prompt user for input
        printf("please enter a string: ");

        // get input and check for CTRL+D
        if (!fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE_WORDS, stdin))
        {
            fputs ("user canceled input\n", stderr);
            exit(1);
        }

         // check if user simply hit enter w/o typing anything
        if(buffer[0] == '\n')
        {
            printf("please enter a word that's more than 0 characters\n");
            // empty_stdin();
            continue;
        }

        size_t inlength = strlen(buffer);

        // check if user input exceed buffer size
        if (inlength >= BUF_SIZE_WORDS - 1)
        {
            empty_stdin();
            fputs ("input exceeds allocated buffer size, please try again\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }

        // check if the user entered too many characters
        if (inlength == BUF_SIZE_WORDS - 1) /* the line was too long */
        {
            printf("you've entered too many characters... please stick to a maximum of %i\n", BUF_SIZE_WORDS);
            empty_stdin();
            continue;
        }

        if (inlength && buffer[inlength - 1] == '\n')
        {
            buffer[--inlength] = 0;

            // get rid of trailing spaces using sscanf
            sscanf(buffer, "%s", valid_input);

            // figure out the length of the word the user entered
            int word_length = ((int) strlen(valid_input));
            printf("string length: %i\n", word_length);

            // print out the word entered by the user one character at a time
            printf("you've entered: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < word_length; i++)
            {
                printf("%c", valid_input[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");

            // increment word count
            word_count++;
            printf("word_count = %i\n", word_count);

            if (word_count == num_words)
            {
                return word_count;
            }
        }
    }
}

/* helper function to remove any chars left in input buffer */
void empty_stdin()
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

things I don't completely understand yet:

1)

```
if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) { /* validate ALL user input */ 
    fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr); 
    return 1; 
}
```

--- does this simply check if the user manually entered EOF (with ctrl+d), or does it check for something else too?

2) calling the empty_stdin() function below seemed to be causing some kind of a weird hang-up where it looked like the program was expecting further input from me as opposed to just going on to the next step, especially when I used it frequently (I figured why not clear the input stream every time the user types in something weird?) and/or when I decreased the buffer to something very small and then purposefully entered too many characters..

```
void empty_stdin()
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

3) eventually I want to use some of this code to load a dictionary from a text file (instead of user input) and store it in a hash table, and, in another version, in a trie. Besides using isalpha() to make sure we're only storing words that have letters in them, are there any other checks/validations that need to happen when processing the input, beside the ones above? Should any of the above checks be skipped?

Comment: You need to allocate more space for `fgets()`.  It can only store the null byte in a string of size 1, so it doesn't read anything.  Forget `malloc()`.  Simply use `char buffer[4096];` and `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);` (preferably checking that you don't get a null pointer returned immediately).  The second code has undefined behaviour because a single character input is not a null terminated string except by accident, but `atoi()` has no way to report "you abused me" (except crashing if the abuse is serious enough).  You are (un)lucky that the second code appeared to work.

Comment: How many characters (+1 for the *nul-terminating* character) does `1` allow you to read in `fgets(input, 1, stdin);`? (but worth the tick for your good effort in providing a well-formatted MCVE)

Comment: Not sure why one would not use scanf when entering a number. Just read into an int with "%d" right away, everything else is unncecessarily complicated (e.g. one cannot diagnose format errors with atoi).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you! 4096 seems really large... As a rule of thumb, shouldn't I try to conserve memory? What would be the smallest number that would be safe to use? Also, I don't really understand why the second code would have undefined behavior -- is this some kind of property of scanf that it only takes one character and doesn't include the null terminator?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Thank you! Could you provide a snippet of code that shows how you'd implement this? As far as not using scanf, I've seen a bunch of discussions on this website where experienced developers are explaining to us newbies why fgets is the only way to go.. I don't really understand all of the explanations, but it seems like the general idea seems to be that scanf and especially gets are unsafe, can cause a buffer overflow, etc.

Comment: You could use a bigger value if you prefer.  You probably have megabytes of Stack; 4KiB isn’t going to hurt and helps avoid problems with lines longer than your buffer.

Comment: Implement: Simply `int num; scanf("%d", &num);`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Seems to me fgets is unsafe, not scanf ;-).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider : really?  Interesting viewpoint. I don’t think I agree.

Comment: It depends on what you conceive as possible.  By default, `scanf()` does not limit the input whereas `fgets()` always does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was thinking of `gets`...

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider : I do my best to forget that `gets()` ever existed.  That is wholly unsafe.  As you recognize, `fgets()` is a very different story.

Comment: Tip: Do not `scanf()` and `fgets()` in the same code until you understand why it should be avoided.  Your most recent - incomplete - code likely uses both.

Comment: @Matvey - let me know if there are still some parts of the code you have not yet made friends with. Now that you have had time to digest, I'm happy for another round in chat if needed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: thanks David! I added some more stuff above (under Edit 2 of the original post) and some questions there - not sure if you've seen that

Comment: Now I did. Your first `if (inlength >= BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS - 1)` isn't needed. That's what `else if (inlength == BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS - 1)` does `:)` Oh boy, `word_input()`... we need to chat... Nuke `if (inlength >= BUF_SIZE_WORDS - 1)` (again). Move `if (inlength == BUF_SIZE_WORDS - 1)` to an `else if` below `if (inlength && buffer[inlength - 1] == '\n')` remove `continue;` from that block. Remove `// get rid of` through `strlen(valid_input);` Change `"string length: %i\n", word_length` to `"string length: %zu\n", inlength` and `printf("%c", valid_input[i]);` to `printf("%c", buffer[i]);` to start.

Comment: Get rid of `if (word_count == num_words)` and just `return word_count;` You only call `empty_stdin()` **if there are characters left in** `stdin`. Why? `getchar()` will *block* waiting for input if none is there. (you wearing your accountants hat, know when this is needed -- it's only needed with `fgets` if the *line was too long*) When you get to your hash table dictionary project, let me know, I think I have one (in fact I know I do). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you David! 

I’ve gone thru your comments, and have the following questions:

1. “Get rid of if (word_count == num_words) and just return word_count” — without this, the for loop just keeps on iterating, asking for more and more words from the user… Is there another way I should be checking if we’ve asked for enough words already?

Comment: 2. “Oh boy, word_input()... we need to chat... “ — I suspect this is because I’m clueless when it comes to naming functions. So far I’ve read that function names need to be descriptive so that it’s easy to tell what that function is doing. I’ve also read that it’s a good idea to put anything that takes user input into separate functions because it’s supposed to make debugging larger projects easier. What am I missing?

Comment: 3. “remove continue; from that block” — wouldn’t it be safer to leave the continue, in case something new is added in this code below the buffer overflow check and ends up getting unintentionally executed before the next iteration of the for loop?

Comment: oops, forgot to tag your name, @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: @Matvey - No need if you "Move `if (inlength == BUF_SIZE_WORDS - 1)` to an **else if** below `if (inlength && buffer[inlength - 1] == '\n')`"

Comment: @Matvey - Don't take that suggestion the wrong way. You are thinking in the right direction, but the `if (...) else if (...)` combination is needed. Why? If you use a separate block, then you need `if (inlength == BUF_SIZE_WORDS - 1 && buffer[inlength - 1] != '\n')` Why? An `inlength` equal to `BUF_SIZE_WORDS - 1` *is fine, so long as* the last character is `'\n'`. Since you are tesing `if (inlength && buffer[inlength - 1] == '\n')`, there is no need to duplicate the test on the last char, just make the `inlength == BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS - 1` test an **else if** to that test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic involved in dealing with strings in C -- but you do need to put your accounting hat on... Why? When dealing with input, you have to not only account for the number of characters that you place into your buffer (or wherever you are storing your input), but you also *must account for the characters that remain in your input stream!*

This is particularly true when using any of the `scanf` family of function for input. Why? Because on a *matching* or *input* failure, processing (reading and removing) characters from your input buffer (`stdin` here) **stops**, no further characters are read, and any character causing the *matching* failure remains **unread** in your input stream, just waiting to bite you again on your next attempted read.

Compounding this bewilderment for new C programmers is the fact that some *conversion specifiers* consume *leading whitespace* (e.g. `space, tab, newline,...`) and others do not. Your *numeric conversion specifiers* (along with `"%s"`) consume leading whitespace while `"%c"` and `"%[...]"` do not.

All of which are the primary reasons new C programmers are encouraged to use *line-oriented* input functions like `fgets` or POSIX `getline` to handle user input (because they read the entire line at a time -- including the trialing `'\n'`) freeing the new programmer for having to account for ending whitespace or offending characters not converted in the event of a *matching* failure...

Using `fgets` followed by a `sscanf` provides the additional benefit of allowing separate **validation** of (1) the read of input; and (2) the parse and conversion of input into the needed values.

(*note:* the only caveat with *line-oriented* input functions is that they *read and include* the trailing `'\n'` in the buffer they fill -- so you will need to "trim" the trailing whitespace as required. You don't want stray `'\n'` characters dangling off the end of the strings you are storing.)

That said, there will be times when reading input with the `scanf` family of functions makes sense. There is nothing wrong with doing so, so long as you ***validate*** the return every time and handle **all three possible conditions**:

1. the user presses <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux to generate a manual `EOF` (<kbd>ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze);
2. you handle the *matching* or *input failure* cases, including removing any offending characters from your input buffer before your next attempted read; and finally
3. you have good input (the return indicates all the conversions anticipated, took place).

There is no magic to any of it, but it does take understanding the possible error conditions and handling each of them on every input.

In your case, let's look at your task of getting the number of words to enter from the user. Here you were attempting to read with `fgets` (that's good!), but you failed to provide sufficient storage to hold the input. When reading small amount of text from the user, a simple array with automatic storage type is all you need. However, you need to size the buffer accordingly (and do NOT skimp on buffer size).

There is no golden rule, but if I had users entering text to convert to a single number, then I would feel good with a `256` character buffer (which provides more than enough to hold the input of any valid number, plus another 230 some-odd characters to handle the time the cat steps on the keyboard, etc..)

For example, taking input from the user and getting the number of words to enter could be done in a manner similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE  10    /* good form defining a constant! */
#define MAXC 256    /* max characters for buffer */

int main (void) {

    int nwords = 0,         /* number of words to enter */
        words = 0,          /* each word */
        wc = 0;             /* word count */
    char buf[MAXC] = "";    /* buffer of sufficient size for input */

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input or user cancels */
        printf ("number of words to enter? [1-%d]: ", SIZE);
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* validate ALL user input */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        /* validate length < MAXC - 1 and buf[length-1] == '\n' here */

        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &nwords) != 1) { /* sscanf for conversion */
            fputs ("  error: invalid conversion to int.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        if (nwords < 1 || SIZE < nwords)  /* validate nwords in range */
            fprintf (stderr, " %2d out of valid range.\n", nwords);
        else  /* good input received, break loop */
            break;
    }
```

(**note:** your `while` loop has been converted to a loop that will loop continually until valid input between `1 < value < SIZE` is entered. The condition simply causes control to `break;` the loop at the point good input is received)

This loop presents a classic `fgets/sscanf` read and parse of information from the line of input entered by the user. You can parse the number from the line any way you like (but don't use `atoi()` -- it provides absolutely **zero** error checking of the conversion). You can use `strtol` (with proper validation) and you can simply use a pointer to walk-down-the-buffer, picking out digits, converting them from their ASCII to numeric value and then multiplying by 10 and adding as your go. Any way is fine so long as you **validate, validate, validate** each part of the operation.

Now turning to reading each of the words the user is supposed to enter, we will ignore conventional wisdom and use `scanf` for the task, but we will handle **all three possible cases of the return** every time. We will also add a counter to keep track of the valid inputs provided by the user and only exit the loop when we have that number of valid integers provided (or the user cancels by generating a manual `EOF`).

```
    printf ("\nnumber of words entered: %d\n", nwords);
    for (; wc < nwords;) {  /* loop continually  */
        int rtn = 0;    /* scanf return */
        printf ("please enter a number between 1 and %d: ", SIZE);
        rtn = scanf ("%d", &words);     /* valdate ALL user input */
        if (rtn == EOF) {           /* handle EOF (manual) */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        else if (rtn == 0) {    /* handle "matching failure" */
            int c = getchar();  /* remove offending chars from stdin */
            while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
                c = getchar();
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        else {  /* valid integer received */
            int c = getchar();      /* remove any extra chars from stdin */
            while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
                c = getchar();
            if (words < 1 || SIZE < words)  /* validate in-range */
                fprintf (stderr, " %2d - invalid! (1 < valid < %d)\n", 
                        words, SIZE);
            else    /* good input, increment word count */
                printf (" word[%2d]: %3d\n", ++wc, words);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** the emptying of any offending characters from `stdin` can be turned into a convenient function so that you do not have to duplicate the loops each time you need to clear `stdin` during your input routine. You can replace it with a simple function, e.g.

```
/* helper function to remove any chars left in input buffer */
void empty_stdin()
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

That will help keep your code tidy. I'll let you incorporate that above.

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE  10    /* good form defining a constant! */
#define MAXC 256    /* max characters for buffer */

int main (void) {

    int nwords = 0,         /* number of words to enter */
        words = 0,          /* each word */
        wc = 0;             /* word count */
    char buf[MAXC] = "";    /* buffer of sufficient size for input */

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input or user cancels */
        printf ("number of words to enter? [1-%d]: ", SIZE);
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* validate ALL user input */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        /* validate length < MAXC - 1 and buf[length-1] == '\n' here */

        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &nwords) != 1) { /* sscanf for conversion */
            fputs ("  error: invalid conversion to int.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        if (nwords < 1 || SIZE < nwords)
            fprintf (stderr, " %2d out of valid range.\n", nwords);
        else 
            break;
    }

    printf ("\nnumber of words entered: %d\n", nwords);
    for (; wc < nwords;) {  /* loop continually  */
        int rtn = 0;    /* scanf return */
        printf ("please enter a number between 1 and %d: ", SIZE);
        rtn = scanf ("%d", &words);     /* valdate ALL user input */
        if (rtn == EOF) {           /* handle EOF (manual) */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        else if (rtn == 0) {    /* handle "matching failure" */
            int c = getchar();  /* remove offending chars from stdin */
            while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
                c = getchar();
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        else {  /* valid integer received */
            int c = getchar();      /* remove any extra chars from stdin */
            while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
                c = getchar();
            if (words < 1 || SIZE < words)  /* validate in-range */
                fprintf (stderr, " %2d - invalid! (1 < valid < %d)\n", 
                        words, SIZE);
            else    /* good input, increment word count */
                printf (" word[%2d]: %3d\n", ++wc, words);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getintstdin
number of words to enter? [1-10]: five, maybe six?
  error: invalid conversion to int.
number of words to enter? [1-10]: -2
 -2 out of valid range.
number of words to enter? [1-10]: 3

number of words entered: 3
please enter a number between 1 and 10: two? three?
  error: invalid integer input
please enter a number between 1 and 10: 2
 word[ 1]:   2
please enter a number between 1 and 10: -2
 -2 - invalid! (1 < valid < 10)
please enter a number between 1 and 10: 11
 11 - invalid! (1 < valid < 10)
please enter a number between 1 and 10: 3
 word[ 2]:   3
please enter a number between 1 and 10: 4
 word[ 3]:   4
```

Note all the invalid inputs above and how the code handles each. So long as the input does not exceed 255-characters with `fgets`, the code will gracefully respond to inputs that are not valid integers (regardless how many are given) and it will respond to integer inputs that are out-of-range.

The code isn't much longer than the code you posted, but it addresses the possible error conditions that could arise and then handles the errors. When you boil it all down, that is what coding is all about. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the detailed explanation! I will look through it more closely and get back to you if I still don't get something. One initial question though: when you talk about "matching failure", does this have to do with scanf being unable to read something from the input? If so, what kinds of things can cause this?

Comment: A *matching failure* occurs when the characters read as input are invalid for the *conversion specifier* provided. For instance if you are using `"%d"` and you enter `"foo"`, a *matching* failure occurs because `"foo"` cannot be converted to an integer value. In that case character extraction stops at the `space` before `"foo"` and `"foo"` is left unread in the input buffer. (and if you tried calling the same `scanf` again... without clearing the offending characters -- an endless loop results) [scanf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) is a good read.

Comment: It may take an hour to read and absorb, but that hour spent will save you dozens of hours wasted fighting with `scanf` in the future if you choose to go the "*I'll just figure it out on my own... route.*" There is no magic to C, but it is an *exact* language. You have total control. You are free to attempt to read 500 characters into a buffer of size 5 -- but bad things will happen. C has blazing speed because it doesn't come with trailing-wheels -- those are up to you to implement. Understand where every byte (character) is coming from, and where it will be stored -- and you will do fine.

Comment: The same goes for all functions you use. Even if you think you know them cold, if there is any question about a parameter or return type, go read the `man page`. They are cryptic at first, but soon you realize they provide exactly the information you need to correctly implement the function. After 30 years, I still go the man page every time I have a question. There is no way you can hold every type or return caveat in your head. Compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS) and don't accept code until it compiles without warning. Best advice I can give.

Comment: Thanks David! I’ve gone through your post more carefully, and there are a bunch of things I don’t understand, most likely because I’m still a beginner. If you have the time, please let me know about the following:

Comment: 1. What is the logic behind ‘if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin))”, and what do you mean by “user canceled input”? Is this related to the situation where there’s still some characters or spaces or a \n hanging out in the input stream, or is there a special way the user can cancel input? Perhaps by not entering anything and pressing enter, or the ctrl+d / ctrl + z thing you were describing? According to the manual, “fgets() returns s on success, and NULL on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read”.

Comment: And if I remember correctly, C interprets 0 as false, and anything other than 0 as true (so any kind of string / characters will be seen as not 0 then right? Is this the case where any symbol corresponds to a number in the ASCII table and then if it’s read, fgets() returns the corresponding number?) Then I guess this if statement checks for user not inputting anything or inputting something weird and classifies this as user cancelling input or something like that? I’ve been starting at this part of the code for about 30 minutes, but I don’t think I’m really understanding what’s happening here.

Comment: Also, when the fgets() is part of the if statement like this, does it actually get called and does its thing, or is this just a test, and no data is actually written to buf? 
2. I also don’t get how “sscanf (buf, "%d", &nwords) != 1” works/ The manual for sscanf() says that it “returns the number of fields that were successfully converted and assigned.” When they say fields, are they talking about bit fields?

Comment: “A bit field is a data structure used in computer programming. It consists of a number of adjacent computer memory locations which have been allocated to hold a sequence of bits, stored so that any single bit or group of bits within the set can be addressed.” If that’s the case, I don’t really understand why they’re discussing things in terms of fields… Aren’t we trying to read characters and then convert them to integers? Is “field” a synonym for “character” in this case, so if the user inputs “10”, we’re dealing with 2 fields?

Comment: Or is that just one field, and if so, what does it look like when we have more or less than 1 field?
3. “/* validate length < MAXC - 1 and buf[length-1] == '\n' here */“ - is this something that you think needs to be added to the code, and if so, what are we checking the length of?
4. When you say “turning to reading each of the words the user is supposed to enter, we will ignore conventional wisdom and use scanf for the task, but we will handle all three possible cases of the return every time,” is this just for illustration purposes, your would you actually recommend doing things this way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182310/discussion-between-david-c-rankin-and-matvey).

Comment: It seems that earlier you were saying that using fgets() is a better strategy for beginners, and there’s an advantage to using fgets() and sscanf() in sequence, I’m assuming for the same task (though I’m still trying to understand exactly why).
5. You said that the second bit of code is for reading the words from user input, yet the code says “printf ("please enter a number between 1 and %d: ", SIZE);”  and looks like it’s really taking in integers (judging by the use of %d, for example).

Comment: 6. Could you provide an example of a typical way of calling gcc with the arguments/attributes you mentioned? “Compile with warnings enabled (-Wall -Wextra for gcc/clang or /W3 for VS) and don't accept code until it compiles without warning.” I’m used to using the built-in function “make” thet was created for the CS50 class I’m currently going through, but I haven’t used gcc properly yet.

Comment: I’m sure I have more questions, but this is probably plenty for now. I’ve spent a few hours researching this at this point, but I only have a very superficial understanding of what you are describing. Any clarification would be very appreciated!